# image intervention out of memory - laravel

Tags: php, laravel, image-processing, memory-leaks, seeding

### Memory Issue: Intevention Image manipulation

I am using intervention image class for laravel and am copying, resizing and encoding images to the sites directory. Essentially simulating an upload to fake listings.

However I seem to be running into a memory issue when running a database seed.

Error Message:

```
local.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' 
with message 'Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 5056 bytes)' 
in C:\xampp\htdocs\equezone\vendor\intervention\image\src\Intervention\Image\Gd\Decoder.php:115
```

Each image is no more than 1265x625. The image is only resized if larger than 1300x700. So therefore no image is actually resized...

**Line 115 of Gd\Decoder.php**

```
$canvas = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
```

`imagecreatetruecolor` appears to extend the gd class for php.

this is the basics of my code:

```
$image = Image::make(( ! is_string($file))? $file->getRealPath(): $file);
if ($image->width() > self::MAX_IMAGE_WIDTH || $image->height() > self::MAX_IMAGE_HEIGHT) {
    self::resizeImage($image, self::MAX_IMAGE_WIDTH, self::MAX_IMAGE_HEIGHT);
}

/*
Some code here to retrieve the listing from the database, 
create an image in the database
assign image to the listing
*/

$image->encode('jpg',100);
$image->save($img->getImageLocation(), 100);
```

I work out where the memory leak is coming from.

The seed will seed roughly 8 - 14 listings before memory crashing. Uploading approximately around 60 - 70 images. Then it runs out of memory. The listings are randomly generated and the images are assigned randomly to the listings...

This has completely got me stumped. If you want any more details about the information just let me know.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using `destroy` to free the memory allocated for the instance after you're done with it:

```
$image->encode('jpg',100);
$image->save($img->getImageLocation(), 100);
$image->destroy();
```

http://image.intervention.io/api/destroy

Comment: you sir, are brilliant. fixed my problem 100%. thanks heaps. i was looking for a method like that, but destroy didnt occur to me... haha.